# how to use a function within same function zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller

Hii...

I have a function something like this...

```
class Zend_View_Helper_RenderUOList extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function makeUOList($inputArray, $main = true, $id ="", $class="")
    {
      ------
      ------
      ------
      $output .= "<li>" . $value['name'] . "\n";
      $output .=  makeUOList($value, false, '', '');
      $output .= "</li>\n";
```

and I am trying to call the same function within the function and I am getting a error message as 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function makeUOList() in C:\dev\workspaces\adxweb\library\Zend\View\Helper\RenderUOList.php on line 99

Any help where I am going wrong... thanx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe because it's class method? :)

`$this->makeUOList...`

Answer (score 1):

Zend has a view helper for generating ordered and unordered lists, take a look at Zend_View_Helper_HtmlList.